# Замена запятой на точку Javascript

Tags: javascript, замена, калькулятор

Здравствуйте!

Есть у меня форма для вычисления площади по ширине и длине. И функция Javascript для вычисления.

```
<div class='controls'>
      <input type="text" id='dlin' onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;"/> х 
      <input type="text" id='shir' onkeyup='Rech()' value="1" style="width: 30px;"/> м
      <span style="margin-left:50px;">Площадь потолка:<span id='ploshad'>0</span> м<sup>2</sup></span> 
    </div>    
<script language="JavaScript">
function Rech() {
var ploshad = document.getElementById('ploshad'),
    dlin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dlin').value),
    shir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shir').value);
ploshad.innerHTML = (dlin * shir).toFixed(2);</script>
```

Вычисления происходят без проблем, вот только при вводе данных на NUM PADе клавиатуры в виде десятичных чисел при русской раскладке - вместо точки ставиться запятая и это мешает корректному вычислению.

Друзья, Подскажите пожалуйста код который будет заменять запятую на точку и куда его внедрить, знаний в Javascript маловато, просьба объяснить по нагляднее!

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: [replace][1]


  [1]: http://javascript.ru/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

Если не заморачиваться с функцией, которая из поля ввода по ид будет получать целочисленное значение, то можно написать так:

```
function Rech() {
  var ploshad = document.getElementById('ploshad'),
  dlin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dlin').value.replace(/,/, '.')),
  shir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shir').value .replace(/,/, '.'));
  ploshad.innerHTML = (dlin * shir).toFixed(2);
}
```

Но в целом, лучше было бы написать функцию, по ид возвращающуу значение:

```
function getFloat(id){
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value .replace(/,/, '.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуй

```
var a =(dlin * shir).toFixed(2);
var str = new String(a);
var st = str.replace(",",".");
ploshad.innerHTML = st;
```

Comment: сколько бесполезных действий, не решающих проблему.

Comment: Поправь если знаешь, как лучше!

Comment: @flashback, вы "ввод" отличаете от "вывода"? запятую надо заменять во входных строках, а не при выводе. При выводе и так будет точка.  
@cheh1, прошу прощения, думал это ваш ответ, а это ваш вопрос... Вам правильно подсказывают используйте replace. Только не к выводу (как в этом ответе), а к входу.

Comment: @flashback

    a.toString();
    a+'';

@cheh1

    dlin = parseFloat(document.getElementById('dlin').value.replace(',','.'))

Comment: var ploshad = document.getElementById('ploshad'),
                dlin = document.getElementById('dlin').value.replace(',', '.'),
                shir = document.getElementById('shir').value.replace(',', '.');
         ploshad.innerHTML = (dlin * shir).toFixed(2);